# Airport Extreme Base Station roaming network crazy ping times

Tags: latency, networking

I have two new AEBS' setup as a roaming network.  One is in the basement (DHCP/NAT) and one in my office (ten feet away) in Bridged mode and is setup with identical SSID/PWD, etc.

The issue is that I am getting wildly differing ping times to the AEBS in my office.  So much so that streaming services stutter repeatedly. There is a clear, clean line of sight between the AEBS and my new Mac Book Pro.  Also of note, this is running over 802.11ac.

Help?

[image: SNR across ten feet of open space]
[image: Ping times]
[image: Network diagram]
[image: UL/DL stats]

Answer (score 0):

According to the signal & noise graph in your top screenshot, you seem to be getting significant noise spikes about three times a minute as well. Have you tried a different channel? AirPort base stations on "Automatic" channel selection only select a channel when first powered on or rebooted. After that they stick to the channel they picked no matter how bad it gets.

If you happen to have an intermittent source of interference in the 5.65–5.73 GHz range (the swath of frequencies used by 802.11ac when you're on channel 132 as your primary channel, and using 80MHz-wide channels), and the interference doesn't happen to be hitting when the base station starts up, then the base station might choose channel 132 because it can't predict that it won't be the long-term best choice.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; unfortunately switching to random channels between 36 & 161 I am seeing similar results. I've also tried renaming the 5GHZ band and joining that network. No luck so far.

Comment: @MattDarby Sometimes ping time variations within that range can be caused by the client device's use of 802.11 power save mode. For a more accurate measure, you've got to ping more often than once per beacon interval, so the client isn't constantly putting its radio to sleep between ping attempts. Since beacon intervals are typically 0.1 seconds, you need do something like: `sudo ping -i 0.05 192.168.10.115`.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same latency issue using a Airport Extreme (nat and dhcp) and a airport express in roaming mode.
Experiencing ping spikes >300ms and 4% loss. And issues with multiroom audio streaming (beolink multiroom, google cast, spotify connect).

If I instead setup airport express to extend network (no ethernet connection to airport express) I could get latency down to 5-8ms and 0% loss. No longer issues with multiroom audio streaming. There is of course about 50% bandwidth loss but it is still fast enough for streaming.

I ended up setting 2x airport express up to extend airport extreme. And then 1x airport express with ethernet that creates another network that I can connect to if I need a faster download.

Anyway not so much a fix as a workaround.

BR